# Deducing extra middle term from inequality with two terms

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

I [found](https://socratic.org/questions/5a36aee2b72cff5100dfcb7c) the following proof:

[image: Proof]

I don't understand how does he get the middle term as it seems to appear from nowhere:

$$ ... < \frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{b}{b + d} + \frac{c}{d} \cdot \frac{d}{b + d} < ... $$

Comment: $\frac r t+\frac s t=\frac {r+s} t$.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I understand your equation, but I don't know how it translates to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{b}{b+d}+\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{d}{b+d}<\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{b}{b+d}+\frac{c}{d}\cdot\frac{d}{b+d}$$ is true because by our assumption: $$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}.$$